# JavaFX NumberAxis turn off Auto Hide/Scale behavior

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

Using JavaFX 2.1 the NumberAxis, when used with a chart such as a ScatterChart, has a feature that as the viewable is resized the chart is resized.The NumberAxis resizes and as it gets smaller it will hide Labels that don't fit, or as it gets bigger will add new ticks between labels that are show. (Even if setMinorTickVisible(false) is called).

In my case I have specific labels I want to use for certain numeric values. So I wrote my own StringConverter and called setTickLabelFormatter() on the NumberAxis

The problem is as it resizes I want to make sure exactly ALL of the labels show up in the display. However resizing will hide the labels I want to show (if it gets too small) or add unwanted ticks if it gets too large.

How can I override the behavior of the Number Axis to not do this?

Or alternatively How can I properly size my chart to show just the labels I need/want (adding a scroll pane if needed).

Thanks for the help I am a long time Java Developer that is just learning JavaFX

Comment: Does the chart need to be re-sizable or can it be a fixed size?

Comment: The chart can be a fixed size however The data is generated dynamically so I don't know the number of labels that will need to be visible until runtime.